# Why is the probability measure P not defined on the power set of $\Omega$, but on it's sigma algebra?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, sigma-algebra

why do we not define P on the power set of $\Omega$, which is equivalent to declaring that all sets are measurable. Even if $\Omega$ is uncountable, it's sigma-algebra and power set would also be- then how do we conclude that only the elements in sigma-algebra are measurable, while others are not

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/why-do-we-need-sigma-algebras-to-define-probability-spaces/199323#199323

Comment: The answer Sycorax linked to is pretty good, and your question appears to be a duplicate.  However, that answer doesn't give an explicit construction of a non-measurable set, i.e. showing that there are members of the power set that lead to a paradox for some probability measures.  The Wikipedia page for [Non-measurable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set#Example) gives such a construction. For me, that example isn't as clear as a similar one in Avner Friedman's [Foundations of Modern Analysis](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486640620.html); I'm sure there are others.

Comment: @Sycorax thankyou, the question missed my attention.

Comment: @Mars this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Great, huy.  It's really kind of an amazing thing when you understand it for the first time, and see why we need to specify a sigma algebra.  At least, that's how I felt.  Note that the point concerns measure in general, not only probability measures.  That is, it also applies to cases in measure theory in which the measure of $\Omega$ is infinite, or is equal to some finite number other than 1.  (If that doesn't make sense to you, don't worry about it--it won't matter unless you study measure theory.)