# How do we choose the sigma algebra for a specific experiment?

Tags: probability, random-variable, measure-theory, sigma-algebra

I am trying to understand the connect between probability and measure theory. I get some basic things about measure theory. But what I still don't get is how do we choose the sigma algebra for our experiment. Suppose that we have two coins, then $\Omega=\{TT,TH,HT,HH\}$. Let $X$ be a random variable (measurable function) for the number of heads $X=\{0,1,2\}$.

Now, how do I choose the sigma algebra on $\Omega$? Can I choose any sigma algebra on $\Omega$ or is the sigma algebra related to our experiment?

Comment: The solution lies in the question itself: the need for $X$ to be measurable limits the choices of sigma algebra.  It doesn't matter which of these you use.  Their intersection is itself a sigma-algebra and (therefore) is the smallest one that makes $X$ measurable.  We say it is "generated by" or "determined by" $X.$

Comment: @whuber, so we can choose any sigma algebra $F$ that makes $X$ a measurable function between $(\Omega, F)$ and $(R,\beta(R))$?

Comment: Wou are going to want your sigma algebra to include the three events you care about.  Since $\Omega$ is finite, you could take the power set of $\Omega$

Comment: @Henry But that's not required.  The sigma algebra generated by this $X$ has only eight  events.  It makes no difference, though, because both sigma algebras include all the events that can possibly be relevant to analyzing $X.$

Comment: @whuber - I agree that it is not required and makes no difference (apart from having $16$ rather than $8$ events in total). Hence my "could"

Comment: You could be interested in:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/why-do-we-need-sigma-algebras-to-define-probability-spaces/199328#199328