# Finite additive probability defined on a "finite-additive" field

Tags: probability, measure-theory, sigma-algebra

Countably additive probability is defined on sigma field. However a finite additive probability needs only a "finite-additive" field: the finite additive probability does not need the countable infinite union of events to still be in the field

To be specific, sigma field requires that countable union of subset is also in the field; a "nonsigma" field  only requires that finite union of subset is also in the field. I think it is enough to have this field to then define a finite additive probability measure.

While the finite-additive measure is well-covered in literature, the finite additive field is not. **Question:** Are there any reference or discussion on this "**finite additive field**"? Does this "non-sigma" field already has a name that I can look up?

---

This is a long comment. I think a "finite additive field" $F$ defined like this suffices:

1. If $A\in F$, then $A^C\in F$.
2. If $A,B\in F$, then $A\cup B\in F$ and $A\cap B \in F$.

Here $A,B$ are sets.

However, when I try to google relevant info, I got no luck. Here are the key words that I tried:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/why-do-we-need-sigma-algebras-to-define-probability-spaces

Comment: Have you tried [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=finitely+additive+measure)?

Comment: @whuber yes of course check my screen shot updated.

Comment: I wonder about an example of an algebra/field that is closed under finite unions, but not under countable unions.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you seek is *premeasure.* More formally, if $\mathcal S$ is any collection of subsets of $X$ then $\mu:\mathcal S\to [0, \infty]$ is a premeasure if it is finitely additive and countably monotone and if $\emptyset\in\mathcal S,$ then $\mu(\emptyset) $ has to be $0.$ $\mathcal S$ is generally taken to be a semiring.

In this [lecture](https://youtu.be/a49_A272dOU), a premeasure is, though, defined as a countably additive measure over the field. If $\mu$ is finitely additive, it is a *finitely-additive measure.*

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Real Analysis, *H. L. Royden, P. M. Fitzpatrick,* Pearson, $2010, $ sec. $17.5, $ p. $353.$

Comment: These primordial measures are the ingredients of construction of full-fledged measures. See Carathéodory-Hahn Theorem.

Comment: The info about "finite additive probability" is well documented. Thanks for the reference! I am a bit more interested in the "finite additive field" which I found no info on google.

Comment: +1 just for the link to the lecture.