# How to define the domain and codomain for the probability function of an uncountable sample space?

Tags: probability

The domain and codomain of a probability function for a discrete sample space can be defined as ...

Domain: Power set of sample space

Codomain: $y \in [0, 1]$

How can I define the domain and codomain for an uncountable sample space? Where should I look for more information?

Comment: you may be interested in the search term "Sigma Algebra".

Comment: I upvoted because someone asked and answered this question about 130 years ago and it led to measure theory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The codomain is easy: probabilities are still in $[0,1]$.  Defining the domain actually gets surprisingly tricky.

If you have a finite or countable sample space, you can work by saying $\{a\}$ has to have a probability for any singleton $a$, and then that you obviously want complements, finite and countable unions and intersections to have probabilities, and that already gets you up to the power set.

If you have even a fairly well-behaved uncountable set such as $\mathbb{R}$, things get more complicated.  Working with singletons won't get you anywhere, since they will typically have zero probability.  You could decide that all intervals $[a,b]$ should have probabilities ($F(b)-F(a)$), and then work with complements and finite and countable unions and intersections of intervals.  That **doesn't** get you to the power set of $\mathbb{R}$.  Let's call what you get ${\cal F}_1$. You'll now want to add in complements, finite and countable unions and intersections of sets in ${\cal F}_1$ to get ${\cal F}_2$. And so on. By doing this infinitely many times you get a set ${\cal F}_\omega$. And we're not done yet -- you need to keep going. Eventually, you end up with a collection ${\cal F}$ where taking complements and finite and countable intersections and unions doesn't give you any more sets.  This is called a $\sigma$-algebra. Specifically, it's called the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for ${\mathbb R}$. You **need to** be able to define the probability on all these sets for the nice machinery of calculus and probability to work.

The interesting question is now how ${\cal F}$  relates to the power set of ${\mathbb R}$. Are they the same? Exactly how they differ depends on your model of set theory, but they are not the same -- there are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that aren't in ${\cal F}$.  You could then ask whether you should add those sets in as well. It can sometimes be worth adding some of them (for example, the sets that are subsets of sets with probability zero), but you can't add all of them in without breaking some property of probability.  The usual counterexample breaks countable additivity of probabilities.

You could also work the other way: start off with the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra and then ask for, say, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all the sets you care about.  For $\mathbb{R}$ this is also the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

So, the standard answer is "The Borel $\sigma$-algebra for your sample space"

There are cases, for example with probabilities on some infinite-dimensional spaces, where even that has problems. In large enough spaces (non-separable), there are too many basic sets (the analog of our intervals in $\mathbb{R}$) for countable unions to capture their behaviour. But for most of statistics it's enough to work with Borel $\sigma$-algebras.

Answer (score 5):

"Probability function" is a [set function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_function): it is, in particular, a [$\sigma$-finite measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure), which basically means that the "measure" of the whole space $\Omega$ is finite (in case of probability, it is $1$).

Measures need not work on power set of $\Omega$- they rather work on a special paving: [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) which is, of course, a subset of the power set.

Suppose, our sample space is real-line, i.e., $\Omega=\mathbb R. $ Then the probability measure $\Pr$ maps a set from the collection of [Borel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set), which is, again, a $\sigma$-algebra$^\dagger,$ denoted by $\mathfrak B(\mathbb R),$ to $[0, 1], $ that is, $$\Pr:\mathfrak B(\mathbb R) \to [0, 1].$$

You can read this [CV thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/why-do-we-need-sigma-algebras-to-define-probability-spaces) on the necessity to work with $\sigma$-algebras.

---

$^\dagger$ For all practical purposes, the spaces, we encounter in statistics, are Polish and hence [second-countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1317147/1074816). So, the Borel $ \sigma$-algebra can be constructed by a countable paving, say $\mathcal C$ (see [countably generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2456422/1074816)), that is, $\mathfrak B(\Omega) =\sigma(\mathcal C). $ For example, in $\mathbb R, ~\mathfrak B(\mathbb R) =\sigma\{(x,~y)\mid x, y\in\mathbb Q\}.$