# Is sample mean an 'efficient' estimator for alpha stable distribution?

Tags: probability, estimation, efficiency, stable-distribution

The question is just like the title. But...$\alpha$-stable distribution (for $\alpha\in (1,2)$) does not have the second moment, so the sample mean doesn't have variance well defined. Then for such a case, it seems sample mean is clearly not efficient?

Is it meaningful to talk about efficiency for the heavy-tailed distribution like $\alpha$-stable distributions? If yes, and if the sample mean is not an efficient estimator of mean, then what it is? (I even don't know how Fisher information is derived for $\alpha$-stable distribution.

Could anyone share an idea or some reference in terms of this topic?

Comment: For distributions without finite variance, the sample mean does not converge to the population mean for large $n$. So that is not a reasonable estimator at all. Finding an optimal estimator is still an active research topic. See for example this recent paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.12433.pdf . This is not an easy problem. Good luck :)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47310/weak-law-of-large-numbers-redundant